# Make path accessible at various level of folder on PHP

Tags: php, path

Assume that I have a folder with some folders and pages on it:

- FolderA

  - PageA1.php
- FolderB

  - FolderB1

    - PageB11.php
  - FolderB2

    - PageB21.php
  - PageB1.php
- FolderC

  - PageC1.php

On **PageB11**, I have:

```
require_once 'FolderB2/PageB21.php';
```

While calling **PageB11** on **PageB1**:

```
require_once 'FolderB1/PageB11.php';
```

It's work fine. But now the problem is, while on **PageB11** also have a function that call the page itself (**PageB11**), then the error showed:

`Warning: require_once(FolderB2/PageB21.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Path\FolderB\FolderB1\PageB11.php on line X`

When I changed the require_once line on **PageB11** become: `require_once '../FolderB2/PageB21.php'`;, it's work!

What I wanna do is, how to make all of it accessible at various level of folder? Is is possible to do that? Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated, the best way of handling such situations, is to refer to each file by its absolute path. This is the path from the root of the filesystem, unlike a relative path which is given relative by the current file.

In PHP you have a magical constant `__DIR__`, which gives the absolute path of the current file. Prepend every include/require with that, and you'll never see that problem again.

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/../FolderB2/PageB21.php';
```

You can also make use of [`realpath()`](http://php.net/realpath).

Comment: I got: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''/../FolderB2/PageB21.php'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in...`

Comment: Ic, thanks it works now. But what I worried while the page being uploaded online, it might not working..

Answer (score 0):

You can add the absolute path to the files

```
require_once('/home/my_host_account/www/FolderB2/PageB21.php');
```

Please verify if this is working.

Comment: It doesn't works. Now I got: `Warning: require_once(/home/my_host_account/www/FolderB2/PageB21.php): failed to open stream:...`. FYI, I am using localhost..

Comment: first call dirname('../FolderB2/PageB21.php') to see which is your root folder. and then put the result into the require_once function.

Answer (score 0):

You can also create [soft-links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) in each directory referring to your original. But this is a workaround that should be used only if all other methods fail.