# Magical Constant doesn't work while the web goes online (PHP)

Tags: php, path

**< Referring to [Make path accessible at various level of folder on PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11840317/make-path-accessible-at-various-level-of-folder-on-php) >**

The code below:

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/../FolderB2/PageB21.php';
```

This works locally, but not when I have uploaded the page to the server. Is my hosting company restricting access to this?

Comment: Quick guess: does the case in the directory and file name match?

Comment: "The code doesn't working". Does that mean you get an error message? If so, it might be extremely helpful if you could tell us *which error message* you get.

Comment: `__DIR__` is only available from PHP 5.3.0. Many hosting companies (ridiculously) still use 5.2.x. Use `dirname(__FILE__)` instead of `__DIR__` to safeguard against this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run this code, do you get the exact path you are expecting?

```
echo dirname(__FILE__) . '/../FolderB2/PageB21.php';
```

Perhaps the relative path is wrong or maybe there is a mistake in the casing (i.e. if your local machine is windows, paths are not case sensitive, but they would be on a Linux server).

Comment: No, the server-side on the hosting restrict the access of using that code. It run well on my localhost...

Comment: @mrjimoy_05: does it say "I restrict the access of using that code"?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/path/to/file.php' if your host runs PHP less than 5.3